# Tunnel wireguard (or any UDP traffic) inside HTTPS

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, udp, wireguard

Wireguard is pretty hot these days, deservedly so. I'm also eager to replace OpenVPN by Wireguard.

However, unlike OpenVPN, Wireguard only supports UDP. I like to use TCP port 443 because this port is  likely  not  blocked by a firewall. OpenVPN even has an option to use an HTTP proxy. This is pretty cool, because it enables me to get full, unrestricted internet access in networks that don't have a route to the internet and require users to use a web proxy instead.

How can I achieve the same with wireguard? An HTTPS tunnel that works for UDP?

Let's assume both endpoints are running Linux, I have full root access to both, and of course I have permission by everyone involved to do this.

Comment: Is TLS (the TLS layer around HTTP, without HTTP itself) good enough? A firewall shouldn't be able to tell the difference...

Comment: That would be a good start, but that still does not replace the OpenVPN feature of using a HTTP proxy

Comment: Ok but then you should provide your reverse proxy HTTP server settings. The tag isn't present, and since the "endpoint" method would change, better know before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/AdrianVollmer/htun/) seems to do exactly what I want, even though you need `cntlm` as an additional proxy if the proxy requires NTLM authentication.

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation says why they don't support TCP and DPI [1]

> WireGuard explicitly does not support tunneling over TCP, due to the classically terrible network performance of tunneling TCP-over-TCP. Rather, transforming WireGuard's UDP packets into TCP is the job of an upper layer of obfuscation

For TCP tunneling they suggest using udp2raw[2] or udptunnel[3].

Note this only covers TCP tunneling, it wont mask it over HTTP(S) so it won't be protected if your firewall performs Deep packet Inspection or header analysis etc . You would need more a advanced setup for that.

1. https://www.wireguard.com/known-limitations/
2. https://github.com/wangyu-/udp2raw
3. https://github.com/rfc1036/udptunnel

Comment: I'm aware of the TCP-over-TCP argument. However, OpenVPN over TCP was never really an issue for me, performance-wise. Plus, terrible performance of TCP-over-TCP is better than no performance in case UDP connections are blocked entirely. And as I explained in my question, I sometimes have the use case where a web proxy is the only way to communicate with the outside world.

Comment: I am not saying your requirement is not valid, just that WireGuard project thinks this is to be done by separate abstraction layer as obfuscation is not a project goal for them. udp2raw is a solid project to transmit over TCP over perhaps 443, however it won't be masked as HTTPS traffic if you have DPI based blocks.
For something like that you should consider SOCKS + Wireguard . This project https://github.com/kizzx2/docker-wireguard-socks-proxy may be useful

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is not something you would use to tunnel traffic, however websockets are suitable for that.

I think you are looking for [WStunnel](https://github.com/erebe/wstunnel). It is capable to tunnel it via TLS as well.

Answer (score -1):

Could run a [SSH VPN](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VPN_over_SSH) (using ssh on port 443) and run the Wireguard over the interfaces created.

Probably could also run Wireguard over your existing OpenVPN.

The premise of Wireguard appears to be connectionless by design so I doubt a TCP or HTTP feature is coming soon (sorry).

Comment: SSH VPN can't use an HTTP proxy and running wireguard on top of OpenVPN defeats the purpose. I realize this won't be coming as a wireguard feature and I understand why, that's why I think an extra tool for this would be useful.